# Should I use `is ranked ...`, `was ranked ...`, or `ranked ...` in the awards section of my CV?

Tags: cv, writing-style, ranking

Should I use `is ranked ...`, `was ranked ...`, or `ranked ...` in the awards section of my CV? E.g.,

- Ranked second (out of at least 11k students) in the Iranian national graduate entrance exam in AI & Robotics of 2022
- Member of INEF

Versus,

- Was ranked second (out of at least 11k students) in the Iranian national graduate entrance exam in AI & Robotics of 2022
- Is a member of INEF

Comment: You should use whichever phrasing is the most consistent with the rest of your CV.  Other than that, I don't see any real reason to choose any one over the others.

Answer (score 2):

**For resume**, depending on the resume styles, sometimes, people would prefer to briefly highlight key points, and may write:

- Ranked first out of 10k students in the national entrance exam in AI
- Member of INEF

**For cover letter (used in a job application process)**, people would certainly write full descriptions, and grammatically correct paragraphs such as "**I was ranked first out of 10k students in the national entrance exam in AI**", and "**I am a member of INEF**".

---

BTW, this question probably fits "**Workplace StackExchange**" better. The link is:  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have heard that `rank` can also be intransitive?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that "is" would not be correct if the exam is offered periodically. The others are fine, but a year should be specified for an annual exam. "National" might also need qualification. Which nation?

In my own case, "Is ranked first among professors at xyz" would (perhaps) have been true at some point in the (far) distant past, but now would be (sadly) incorrect.

Comment: I had abbreviated the sentences in the question, which I am going to now revert. The originals did mention the details.

Comment: Looks fine now.